# using do..while ,continue?

Tags: php, loops

```
<?php
// initial value

$week = 50;
$year = 2001;
$store = array();
do
  {
  $week++;
  $result = "$week/$year";
  array_push($store,$result);
  if($week == 53){
    $week = 0;
    $year++;//increment year by 1
    }
    continue;
  }
// End of Loop
while ($result !== "2/2002");

?>

print_r($store);
```

result want return will be

```
array("51/2001", "52/2001", "01/2002", "02/2002");
```

What is my problems by using while using do..while ,continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- <strike>Your arguments to `array_push` are the wrong way around. Read the manual entry for functions you use. Turn on warnings on your server; [running](http://codepad.org/kUoqLgL8) this in codepad showed me the problem immediately.</strike> *[**Edit:** You have now quietly fixed that in your question.]*
- You also have a typo: `$i` instead of `$week`.
- Finally, you test against "02/2002", but for that month the string will be "2/2002".

Fixed code ([live demo](http://codepad.org/mUPnYsRE)):

```
<?php
// initial value

$week = 50;
$year = 2001;
$store = array();
do
  {
  $week++;
  $result = "$week/$year";
  array_push($store, $result);
  if($week == 53){
    $week = 0;
    $year++;//increment year by 1
    }
    continue;
  }
// End of Loop
while ($result !== "2/2002");
?>
```

In general, I'd recommend *against* loops like this. As you've discovered, your code is very fragile because you're testing for just one very specific value, and if that value is not precisely correct you get an infinite loop.

Instead, consider comparing `$week` and `$year` separately and numerically:

```
while ($week < 2 && $year <= 2002)
```

---

Next time please include in your question the output that you *are* seeing, as well as the output that you want to see. It'll save us time in reproducing your problem.

Comment: The arguments for `array_push` are correct - `array_push($arr, $value)`. As you noted, RTFM - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: @Jason: The OP fixed that in his question by editing. Look at the question's revision history.

Answer (score 0):

I may not be understanding this correctly... If you could explain a bit more that'd help.

Try turning the loop into a function, and turn the while(..) to check the functions variable.

then just call it 4 times to fill your array.